# Blank white space around Timepicker dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am trying to create a time picker for my application..
and when setting the theme to `Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth`

I am getting this output

[image]

I am getting a blank space around the dialog box

This is not happening when I am setting it to use the parent activity's theme which is `appcompat.noactionbar`

```
//not happening here
  return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,is24HourView );
```

Here is my timepicker code

```
    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        boolean is24HourView=true;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String formattedTime = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        Log.d("time", formattedTime);
        //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
//        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,is24HourView );
      return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth,this, hour, minute,is24HourView );

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
 android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth
```

with

```
 AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
```

or

```
 AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
```

It should work

Comment: It says deprecated..:/

Comment: doesn't matter at all... Deprecated means that this feature would not be anymore upgraded. In fast-moving/changing Android World `deprecated is pretty often word

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but here is a solution.

You could make a custom theme in `styles.xml` with your chosen theme as a parent, and set it's `android:windowBackground` attribute to `@android:color/transparent`:

```
<style name="TimePickerDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then pass your custom theme to the `TimePickerDialog` constructor:

```
new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.TimePickerDialogStyle, this, hour, minute, is24HourView);
```